# Why is query failing when using order by

Tags: mysql

My query is failing everytime I run it. This error keeps showing

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'BY b.bidId DESC' at line 1Database select query failed.

```
public static function getAuctionBids( $auctionId, $limit = null )
    {
        self::getDatabaseInstance();

        // SQL query for retrieving all bids for a specific auction
        $bidsQuery  = "SELECT u.username AS bidderName, u.userId AS bidderId, b.bidTime, b.bidPrice ";
        $bidsQuery .= "FROM auctions a, bids b, users u ";
        $bidsQuery .= "WHERE a.auctionId = b.auctionId AND b.userId = u.userId AND a.auctionId = $auctionId ";
        $bidsQuery .= "ORDER BY b.bidId DESC";
        $bidsQuery .= ( is_null( $limit ) ) ? "" : " LIMIT " . $limit;
        $result = self::$database -> issueQuery( $bidsQuery );

        $bids = [];
        while ( $row = $result -> fetch_assoc() )
        {
            $bid = new Bid( $row );
            $bids[] = $bid;
        }

        return $bids;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that `$auctionId` is not `null`?

Comment: `echo $bidsQuery` and check the query; maybe some input variables (params) dont have value in them.

Comment: agreed, more than likely there's a problem with $auctionId. P.S. I would advise you to a) use proper ANSI INNER JOIN syntax instead of comma-separated, and b) use parameterised queries to reduce the risk of SQL Injection attacks and also make syntax errors such as this much less likely.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i got to know that $auctionId was empty for that particular item. It was deleted from the auction table unknowing to me.